# Is every prime gap bounded from above by $C\cdot \ln^2(p_n)$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

It is known that the merit of a prime gap can be arbitary large : The merit is defined by $$\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\ln(p_n)}$$ , where $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ are consecutive primes.

> Does a constant $C$ exist such that for every prime $p_n$ the inequality $$p_{n+1}-p_n\le C\cdot \ln^2(p_n)$$ holds, when $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ are consecutive primes ? If yes, what is the best known constant $C$ ?

Comment: For $p \geq 11$ all existing tables allow for $C=1.$ There is absolutely no chance of proving anything like this; the best proven results have  gap $g \approx p^{0.55}$ and no better

Comment: This is Cramer's weak conjecture. Do you know the random model for the primes ? Under this model $X_n = 1_{n \text{ is prime}}$ is a sequence of **independent** random variables with $P(X_n=1) = \frac{1}{\log n}, P(X_n=0)= 1-\frac{1}{\log n}$. What do you get from this model for the probability distribution of the $n$-th gap $G(n)$ ?

Comment: @WillJagy I think the exponent should be $0.525$, not $0.55$, but of course this not diminish the overall point.

Comment: @ErickWong thanks. "A result, due to Baker, Harman and Pintz in 2001, shows that θ may be taken to be 0.525"   I see they have extended maximal prime gaps up to nearly $7 \cdot 10^{18},$ although they do not seem to identify $M$ in "this list is complete up to $M$" For a few years they were stuck with the list up to   $4 \cdot 10^{18}.$ I guess this is what happens when a new investigator gets involved, reach new plateaus.